# How to find a value in object of objects with an array of keys

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

for example I have an object that that has objects and arrays in itself:

```
const object = 
{
    a: {
        b: [
            0: 'something',
            1: {
                c: 'the thing that I need',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

and an array that has the keys as values:

```
const array =
[
   'a', 'b', '1', 'c',
];
```

How can I use this array to navigate in the object and give me the value?
Maybe there is a way to do this with `ramda`? or just in general to make it look human readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reduce the array defining the path through the object.
You do have an error in the array. The path should be: [ 'a', 'b', '1', 'c' ], because the thing you need is inside the second element of the b array, not the first.

```js
const object = {
  a: {
    b: [
      'something',
      { c: 'the thing that I need' }
    ],
  },
};
const path = [ 'a', 'b', '1', 'c' ];
const result = path.reduce(( source, next ) => source[ next ], object );
console.log( result );
```

Comment: One difference between this and the Ramda `path` function is that this one will throw if an intermediate path is missing.  Ramda will return `undefined`.  And `pathOr` lets you supply the value to choose in this case.  Whether or not this is important to you will depend on your application and its data.  But it can be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

Ian Hoffman-Hicks' superb [crocks](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks) library has a function that does exactly that

```
import propPathOr from 'crocks/helpers/propPathOr'
const getC = propPathOr(null, ['a', 'b', '0', 'c'])
getC({ a: { b: [{ c: 'gotcha!' }] } }) === 'gotcha!' // true
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is called [`path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) in Ramda.